# how to use SearchCriteria class to search user on many terms given by user in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, search, spring-data-jpa

I have a class called `SearchCriteria` in which i have properties by which user can search.
how to use this class with spring data jpa for searching the data. In below example.
I am using `JpaRepository` for creating repositories.
should i make repository for `SearchCriteria` also and same entity also not not needed or any way to do this.

```
@Entity
class User{  

    @Id
    id;

    fname;
    lname;
    location;
    orders;
    posts;

    //getters & setters
}


class SearchCritiea {
    int radius;//search user in given diameter 
    String fname;
    int ordercount;//search users with oder count  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery` to dynamically define queries:

https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: i have to use SearchCriteria class can i do it with this class i am new to Data Jpa

Comment: You'll have to use one of JPA's classes. I doubt that you can use your class directly. @cristian 's answer also seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Specifications To be able to define reusable Predicate:

```
public CustomerSpecifications {

public static Specification<Customer> customerHasBirthday() {
return new Specification<Customer> {
  public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    return cb.equal(root.get(Customer_.birthday), today);
   }
 };
```

}

```
public static Specification<Customer> isLongTermCustomer() {
return new Specification<Customer> {
  public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    return cb.lessThan(root.get(Customer_.createdAt), new LocalDate.minusYears(2));
    }
   };
  }
}
```

Now you can use this predicates linking with AND, OR NOT OPERATION:

```
  customerRepository.findAll(where(customerHasBirthday()).and(isLongTermCustomer()));
```

See Spring oficial blog entry: https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: i have  table searchcriteria this will store the search terms also entity called SearchCriteria

Comment: do you need to store all use of a search method inside your database? Which would be de principal purpose of your SearchCriteria entity model?

Comment: in database need to store what users prefer to search next time i want to  suggest based on his last search preferences any idea if its not good principal please

Comment: Perhaps relational database is not the best way to do it. Get a Try elasticsearch document database using lucene.